# Spherical harmomics to hemispherical harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, spherical-harmonics

I was asked a question about finding the wave function of a particle trapped in a hemisphere.

No other boundary conditions were mentioned except that the base of hemisphere lies in xy plane with a radius $r$.

I tried to solve Schrödinger's equation assuming potential outside is infinity and inside is zero. But I was unable to work out this specific example due to the hemispherical shape.

How do spherical harmonics transform in this case? Or is there anything like hemispherical harmonics?

Comment: Are you sure the particle is _in_ the hemisphere (in which case $\psi(R)=0$), or is the particle _on_ the hemisphere, in which case you need some mixtures of $Y_{lm}$ that are zero at $\theta = \pi/2$. (The latter is a more reasonable problem, IMHO).

Comment: @JEB the particle is _in_ the hemisphere where potential is zero and outside potential is infinite.

Comment: Then you need $\psi(R)=0$ *and* $Y_{lm}(\theta=\pi/2, \phi)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, for example, that:

$$ Y_1^0 \propto z $$

$$ Y_2^{\pm 1} \propto z $$
$$ Y_3^{\pm 0} \propto z(5z^2-3r^2) $$
$$ Y_3^{\pm 2} \propto z $$

so that, probably, as long as $l$ is even (odd) and $m$ odd (even), then $Y_{lm}$ is zero along the base of the hemisphere.

Combine those with radial free-space wave functions that are zero at the hemi-spherical boundary and finite at the origin and you should have a solution, as the boundary conditions are met and the free space S.E. is solved in the volume.